# Error in gdal2tiles with --processes

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

```
gdal2tiles -w leaflet --processes=2 -x -a 0 -z 1-15  mercator.tif tiles.webtiles
```

Using gdal from QGIS 3.22.0

this command gives this error immediately after start. Without the processes parameter it runs fine. So how to speed up things with multiple threads? Its an i7 windows 10 pc with 4 cores.

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py", line 3257, in main
    multi_threaded_tiling(input_file, output_folder, options)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py", line 3206, in multi_threaded_tiling
    pool = Pool(processes=nb_processes)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    w.start()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Python issue https://bugs.python.org/issue42949 is probably the reason for the failure. Python 3.7 should work fine. You can select the Python version that OSGeo4W installs with the advanced settings of the installer.

There may be some change in multiprocessing in Python version higher than 3.7 and therefore gdal2tiles does not work with --processes. I suggest to write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask if you should create a ticket into GitHub issues.

I had a try with OSGeo4W command window with Python 3.7 and command was running OK

```
gdal2tiles -w leaflet --processes=2 -x -a 0 -z 1-15  test.tif tiles.webtiles
Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
Generating Overview Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
```

However, with another OSGeo4W installation with this Python

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52)
 [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I get immediately the same errors than you:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
```

Comment: Ok, I wouldn't mind to use another version of  OSGeo4W with Python 3.7. Which version of OSGeo4W did you use?

Comment: I do not know, it has been staying on my computer for some time. It has installed me GDAL 3.1.3 and default Python is 2.7 but `py3_env` is changing it into 3.7.